# Is there any conversions when storing/reading integers of different size to/from union?

Tags: c++, optimization, endianness, rapidjson

Reading Rapidjson code I found some interesting optimization with "type punning".

```cpp
    // By using proper binary layout, retrieval of different integer types do not need conversions.
    union Number {
#if RAPIDJSON_ENDIAN == RAPIDJSON_LITTLEENDIAN
        struct I {
            int i;
            char padding[4];
        }i;
        struct U {
            unsigned u;
            char padding2[4];
        }u;
#else
        struct I {
            char padding[4];
            int i;
        }i;
        struct U {
            char padding2[4];
            unsigned u;
        }u;
#endif
        int64_t i64;
        uint64_t u64;
        double d;
    };  // 8 bytes
```

It looks like only BE CPUs are affected by this optimization. How does this increases performance? I'd like to test but do not have BE machine.

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Optimization):

> While not allowed by C++, such type punning code is allowed as "implementation-defined" by the C11 standard[15] and commonly used[16] in code interacting with hardware.[17]

So is it legal in C++? I believe in absolute most cases it works fine. But should I use it in new code?

Comment: It is not legal according to the C++ Standard. C11 is for the C language, not C++.

Comment: I see. But this library is presented as the fastest FOSS serializer/parser on all the internet. So It works fine. And has 9K9 stars on GitHub.

Comment: If “Not allowed by C++” means that the code is ill-formed, the requirement is only that a conforming compiler must issue a diagnostic. Having done that, the compiler is free to compile the code, with an implementation-specific meaning. So, if it works, it works. If it doesn’t work, don’t blame the C++ standard. <g>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is it legal in C++?

No, it isn't legal in c++ (Wikipedia also already stated *"While not allowed by C++ ..."*).

In c++ a `union` is just reserving memory for the contained `union` members, such that it is enough to fit the largest member. That memory is shared by all members.

Accessing a different member from the union as was used to initialize it, is *undefined behavior*. You need to decide beforehand with which `union` members to work, if these are shared by any functions (this is often done using a *type discriminator*).

Comment: What is type discriminator?

Comment: @kyb It's usually something like `struct foo { enum members { x , y } type_; union { int a; std::string b; } bar; }; ` where `type_` is used to decide to access union member `bar.a` or `bar.b`.

Comment: @kyb Yup, `std::variant` is a generic union if you want so.